# Querying based on the count of an object's children ActiveRecord Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've been trying to setup my hashtagging query to add only hashtags with children that have more than zero post inside of the view, and then I want to list the hashtags from least to greatest in terms of how many people used the hashtag. (To show which hashtags are trending)

What I've done so far, is list the hashtags created_at descending, but it's not structured to take into account the amount of posts. I'll have to destroy old records of hashtags that aren't being used with the clean_orphans method. Probably using sidekick or activejob

gem 'simple_hashtag'

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
include SimpleHashtag::Hashtaggable
hashtaggable_attribute :body
end
```

hashtags_controller.rb

```
@hashtags = SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.order('created_at DESC').limit(10).uniq
```

_hashtag_list.html.erb

```
<% if @hashtags.present? %>
      <ul>
        <% @hashtags.each do |hashtag| %>
            <li><i class="fa fa-hashtag" aria-hidden="true"></i><%= link_to hashtag.name, hashtag_path(hashtag.name) %></li>
            <li><%= hashtag.hashtaggables.count %> </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: You need to specify the relationships among models that are involved in identifying "*how many people used the hashtag*". Otherwise, it is not clear how to do it, nor possible to answer.

Comment: I'm using simple_hashtag gem, which creates a polymorphic relationship between the model and itself. I just had to add the "include SimpleHashtag::Hashtaggable" and "hashtaggable_attribute :body" to the post model. It saves the hashtags into the hashtag table as a string :name.

Comment: It's just that, the gem includes empty hashtags into the list, that may have destroyed posts. When you click on the link_to show action, the page is empty. It could be the gem causing this issue. But, what I need is to rank the list of hashtags from least to greatest with the count method. Most used hashtags at the top, least used at the bottom. I'll utilize the clean orphan method to destroy old posts with a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I simply checked for empty hashtaggable items on the list.

```
<% @hashtags.each do |hashtag| %>
<% if hashtag.hashtaggables.count > 0 %>
<% display hashtag %>
<% end %>
```